# How to integrate a new ionic theme to an existing ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, themes

i'm working on an ionic v1 (and angular 1) project which is completed using basic ionic UI. I came across various themes on ionic marketplace. How do i integrate a new ionic theme to my existing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have Ionic setup in your local machine.

Once you've purchased and downloaded the files of the theme you want to use, create an **ionic1** project. Note this will work only with Ionic1, and not Ionic2. Use the following command to create an ionic1 project:

```
ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1
```

When your project has been created, go to the /www folder in your project directory, delete all files in here, and copy the theme's files you've downloaded here.

Run `ionic serve` and your project should have integrated with the theme.

PS. you might have to replace the project scss folder with that of the theme's if available.